# php, не могу распарсить json

Tags: php

С сервера API приходит запрос post(x-www-form-urlencoded) со значением(print_r):

```
Array
(
    [status] => 3
    [goods] => {\"alias_ZhOSTOVOChERN1488881464\":{\"goodID\":\"8419\",\"name\":\"ЖОСТОВО ЧЕРН\",\"quantity\":\"1\",\"price\":\"1990\"}}
)
```

Но при попытке получить goods:

```
$goods = json_decode($_POST['goods']);
```

Переменная $goods всегда пустая.. Если просто вывести:

```
echo $_POST['goods'];
```

То все отлично выводит, а вот json_decode возвращает пустоту. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: В том, что у вас все кавычки экранированы. И декодирование возвращает null

Comment: Тут либо высылайте валидный json либо предварительно почистите от экранирования. В доках написано: // Имя и значение должны помещаться в двойные кавычки.

Comment: Если будет залетать примерно такое: `{\"key\":\"\u0022\u00e9\u0022\"}` - то не получится обычными способами выиграть, вида `striplashes`, так как ими мы сломаем данные и `json_decode` будет молчать. Чувство. что у вас `magic_quotes`.

Comment: Кстати, json_decode($JSONText) возвращает объект, чтобы вернул массив - нужно вторым аргументом передать true. http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-decode.php

Вы можете проверить свой JSON-код тут http://json.parser.online.fr/ будет ошибка.

Answer (score 0):

Если на стороне сервере ничего изменить нельзя, то как сказал [@Moonvvell](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/191079/moonvvell), нужно предварительно почистить от экранирования.

Самый простой способ - это убрать экранирование одной заменой перед декодированием

```
$string=str_replace('\"','"',$_POST['goods']);
```

И тогда все нормально работает - [Демо](https://eval.in/751096)

Это самая простая замена, если будут проскакивать ошибки (например при наличии в тексте конструкций \" - то замены нужно сделать более сложными, цеплять при замене скобки, ( например заменят **{\"** на **{"**) и т.д.

Comment: Зачем, когда есть `stripslashes`. Для этих целей.

Answer (score -1):

Похоже, json закодирован 2 раза. Вот так работает.

```php
<?php
$str = '{\"alias_ZhOSTOVOChERN1488881464\":{\"goodID\":\"8419\",\"name\":\"ЖОСТОВО ЧЕРН\",\"quantity\":\"1\",\"price\":\"1990\"}}';
var_dump(json_decode(json_decode('"' . $str . '"'), true));
```